# Optimizing a rank 3 tensor

Tags: mathematical-optimization

Assume we have the following elements 
\begin{equation}
F_i{}^j \;and\; S_{ij}{}^k,
\end{equation}
which represent the components of tensorial objects of ranks 2 and 3 respectively, with Complex coefficients.

Let the components of $F$ be given by

$F_1{}^j$ = 
\begin{matrix}
  0 \\
  -x-iy \\
  -i(-1+x^2+2ixy-y^2+z^2)/2z \\
  (1-x^2-2ixy+y^2+z^2)/2z 
\end{matrix}

$F_2{}^j$ = 
\begin{matrix}
  x+iy \\
  0\\
(1-x^2-2ixy+y^2+z^2)/2z\\
  i(-1+x^2+2ixy-y^2+z^2)/2z
 \end{matrix}

$F_3{}^j$ = 
\begin{matrix}
i(-1+x^2+2ixy-y^2+z^2)/2z\\
-(1-x^2-2ixy+y^2+z^2)/2z \\
0\\
-x-iy
\end{matrix}

$F_4{}^j$ = 
\begin{matrix}
-(1-x^2-2ixy+y^2+z^2)/2z\\
-i(-1+x^2+2ixy-y^2+z^2)/2z\\
 x+iy\\
 0
\end{matrix}

($j=1,2,3,4$).  We would like to solve for the components of $S$ if they satisfy the following equation

\begin{equation}
S_{li}{}^jF_k{}^l-S_{lk}{}^jF_i{}^l=0,
\end{equation}

where $l$ is summed over, all the indices run from 1 to 4, and $S$ is symmetric in the lower indices.

Would it be possible to write a code that find the components of $S$? The code provided in my previous question [Solving antisymmetric tensorial equation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/10853/solving-antisymmetric-tensorial-equation) would work well for simple examples of $F$, but not for the example we have here.

Comment: What does your notation mean, exactly? Assuming the superscript $i$ is intended to run from $1$ through $4$ in each one of the four equations, each of which appears to list a four-vector, you are providing $64$ entries for a four by four matrix $F$!

Comment: @whuber Thanks for the comment. I'm just providing 16 entries. Example F_1^i={F_1^1,F_1^2,F_1^3,F_1^4}, which represents the first column in the 4x4 matrix.

Comment: May I suggest you to post the Mathematica code for your `Fs` ?

Comment: I still cannot make sense of your notation: what, then, is "$i$" in the formulas? Is it (a) the Imaginary unit, (b) supposed to increase from $1$ to $4$ as we go down each column vector, (c) some other free variable, or perhaps something else?

Comment: @whuber $i$ in the formulas is the imaginary unit.

Comment: OK, I modified your notation slightly to make this apparent.  Given that your equations are linear, why don't you just write them down in matrix form and request the kernel with `NullSpace`?

Comment: @whuber If you mean write all the equations down, like expand for all the indices, then we are talking about 64 equations, which, to me, doesn't sound practical.

Comment: *Mathematica* (and much other software) can quickly solve systems of tens of thousands of equations. This problem is even practicable with a spreadsheet...

Comment: I agree, but the way I would use to write the program would take days of typing, perhaps there is a concise way of writing down the matrix that you can code here!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The equations (along with the symmetry constraints on $S$) are linear and homogeneous.  All we have to do is write them down and find a basis for the solution space using `NullSpace`.

---

#### Strategy

Doing this efficiently *for the analyst* takes several steps: simplifying $F$ using common factors, then converting the $_{li}^{\ \ j}$ indexing into a single integer index starting at $1$.  (Who cares about the program's efficiency?  It won't need more than a second or two anyway.)

#### Simplifying $F$

```
ClearAll[x, y, u, v, z];
rules = {u -> x + I y, v -> (1 - x^2 - 2 I x y + y^2)/z};
f = {{0, -u, I (v - z)/2, (v + z)/2}, {u, 0, (v + z)/2, -I (v - z)/2}, 
     {-I (v - z)/2, -(v + z)/2, 0, -u}, {-(v + z)/2, I (v - z)/2, u, 0}} ;
f /. rules // Transpose // MatrixForm
```

This expresses $F$ more simply in terms of common factors, then displays it in a nice form for confirmation.

[image: F Tensor]

#### Dealing with tensor indices

Now some functions to convert indexes reliably and to display them for later output:

```
index[l_, i_, j_] := j + 4 (i - 1 + 4 (l - 1));
invIndex[n_] := PadLeft[IntegerDigits[n - 1, 4], 3] + 1 (* l, i, j *);
sIndexes = Flatten[Table[index[i, j, k], {k, 1, 4}, {i, 1, 4}, {j, i, 4}]];
sLabels = Flatten[Table[
    ToString[i] <> ToString[j] <> ToString[k], {k, 1, 4}, {i, 1, 4}, {j, i, 4}]];
i = Ordering[sIndexes];
sIndexes = sIndexes[[i]];
sLabels = sLabels[[i]];
```

#### Creating the matrix of equations

With these preliminaries out of the way, we can create the matrix of equations using pattern replacement, so that the computation closely follows the original tensor equations in form:

```
a = Module[{s, eqns, sym, x, t}, 
   (* The relationship between S and F *)
   eqns = Cases[Flatten[Table[
     List @@ (Collect[Sum[s[l, i, j] f[[k, l]] - s[l, k, j] f[[i, l]], {l, 1, 4}], s[a___]]
        /. Times[s[l0_, i0_, j0_], x_] :> ({index[i, j, k], index[l0, i0, j0]} -> x)),
     {k, 1, 4}, {j, 1, 4}, {i, 1, 4}]], _Rule];
   (* The symmetry of S *)
   t = index[4, 4, 4];
   sym = Flatten[Table[++t; {{t, index[i, j, k]} -> 1, {t, index[j, i, k]} -> -1}, 
       {k, 1, 4}, {i, 1, 4}, {j, i, 4}] ];
   SparseArray[eqns~Join~sym]
   ];
```

(This exploits the fact that no entries of $F$ are equal to $1$, so that *everything* in the sum will have a `Times` header.  `Cases` strips out all equations that are identically zero.  Although unnecessary in this application, `Collect` ensures that each set of subscripts appears only once in each equation.)

This array is $104$ by $64$ with symbolic coefficients.  Here is a plot of its potentially nonzero entries:

[image: Matrix]

#### The solution

```
zero = NullSpace[a];
sDimensions = Length[zero]
```

#### Verifying the solution

The output of `12` indicates there is a 12-dimensional space of solutions.  As a check, let's systematically apply the original equations to each basis element in the null space.  First, a function `s` extracts the coefficients of any solution for $S$ given as a linear combination with coefficients in a vector `x`:

```
ClearAll[s];
s[x_List] /; Length[x] == sDimensions := x.zero;
s[x_List, {l_, i_, j_}] := s[x][[index[l, i, j]]];
```

Now the check:

```
Module[{x},
 Select[Table[
     x = UnitVector[sDimensions, m]; 
     Sum[s[x, {l, i, j}] f[[k, l]] - s[x, {l, k, j}] f[[i, l]], {l, 1, 4}],
       {i, 1, 4}, {j, 1, 4}, {k, 1, 4}, {m, 1, sDimensions}
     ] // Flatten // Simplify, # != 0 &]
 ]
```

The output is empty (`{}`), confirming that all the rows of the putative solution really do solve the equation (and that our method of indexing via `s` is correct, too).

#### Displaying the solution

Finally, we can look at the solution.  `TableForm` (instead of `MatrixForm`) enables us to head the columns with the $_{ij}^{\ \ l}$ indexes of $S$ rather than the integral indexes used in the array.  At this time we may also apply the rules converting `F` back into expressions involving `x`, `y`, and `z`:

```
TableForm[zero[[All, sIndexes]]  /. rules, TableHeadings -> {{}, sLabels}]
```

To shorten the table, the symmetry of the lower indexes of $S$ is exploited to display only $S_{ij}^l$ for $i\le j$.

[image: Tabled solution]

Comment: That's a wonderful answer!!! My paper will see the sun soon, and you will definitely be among the acknowledged people. Thanks a mil...

Comment: Just make sure you double- and triple-check the solution to make sure it's right :-).  Incidentally, it's curious that $F$ is *formally* Hermitian (when expressed in terms of $u$ and $v$) but it isn't really (once it is expanded in terms of $x$, $y$, and $z$).

Comment: $F$ is not Hermitian in $u$ and $v$.

Comment: You're right: $F$ is antisymmetric in $u$ and $v$.  (Check: `f + Transpose[f] // Simplify` returns the zero matrix.)